# System.InvalidCastException iterating through Viewdata

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, html-helper

System.InvalidCastException iterating through Viewdata

I need to replace the code

```
"<%=Html.DropDownList("Part", (SelectList)ViewData["Parts"])%>
```

for dropdown in the following manner for some reason.

```
 <select> <% foreach (Hexsolve.Data.BusinessObjects.HSPartList item in (IEnumerable<Hexsolve.Data.BusinessObjects.HSPartList>)ViewData["Parts"])
               { %>
            <option value="<%=item.Id %>">
                <%=item.PartName %>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <%=item.IssueNo %></option>
            <% } %>
        </select>
```

I am getting error converting SelectedList to IEnumerable)

Error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Hexsolve.Data.BusinessObjects.HSPartList]'.

Is this the right way to iterate through viewdata[]. Please help me out of this.

Comment: If you have a further problem you should add it as a comment or create a new question. You have completely changed your question meaning my answer below now doesn't make the slightest bit of sense. I have already given you a thorough answer to the problem. If you don't want to use it then fine, but don't change the question.

Comment: Sorry i shall change qst to old qst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my previous answer was incorrect.

I believe the problem is that `GetEnumerator` returns `IEnumerator<SelectListItem>`, not `IEnumerator<Hexsolve.Data.BusinessObjects.HSPartList>` which you are trying to access.

I would suggest something like the following should work:

```
<% foreach (SelectListItem item in (SelectList)ViewData["Parts"])
{ %>
    <option value="<%= item.Value %>"><%= item.Text %></option>
<% } %>
```

If you need to concatenate `PartName` and `IssueNo` in the `Text` property which it looks like you're trying to do, you could do that while building the select list.

So you might end up with something like:

```
 public class Part
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int IssueNo { get; set; }
     public string PartName { get; set; }
 }
```

and

```
   var parts = new List<Part>{
             new Part { Id = 1, IssueNo = 1, PartName = "Spanner" },
             new Part { Id = 2, IssueNo = 1, PartName = "Hammer" }
         };

   var selectList = new SelectList(
         parts.Select(p => 
                new { Id = p.Id, 
                      Name = p.PartName + " " + p.IssueNo.ToString()}),
         "Id",
         "Name");

   foreach (var item in selectList)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
       Console.WriteLine(item.Text);
   }

   /* 
   Output:
   1
   Hammer 1
   2
   Spanner 1
   */
```

Hope that helps!